# Prevent route from being rendered

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using **Next.js**.

I currently have **3 routes**: `"/"`, `"/login"` and `"register"`.

When accessing `"/login"` or `"/register"` the `"/"` page appears **shortly**.

I want the `"/"` page **not to appear** when accessing `"/login"` or `"/register"`.

The following code is from my `_app.js` file:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
        setUser({ token })
        setLoading(false)
    } else if (router.pathname === '/register') {
        setLoading(false)
    } else {
        router.push('/login')
        setLoading(false)
    }
}, [])
```

Any thoughts on how to **prevent** the `"/"` page from being rendered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept that you are looking for is 'server-sided data fetching in Next.js'. You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).

The problem lies in your `useEffect`. Remember that `useEffect` is run **after** the component has mounted. Also, `localStorage` is client-side, so the server will not be able to access it. In my humble opinion, I think it will be better if you store your token via cookies.

This snippet should help you. You might have to refactor your code a bit, so you can store the token in cookies. Make sure to place this snippet in one of the pages in the `pages` folder, because if you place it inside a component that is not in the `pages` folder, **it will not work!**

```js
export const getServerSideProps = (ctx) => {
  const { token } = ctx.req.cookies;

  // If token does not exist, return back to '/'.
  if (!token) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      }
    }
  }

  // If token exist, return the user data as props.
  return {
    props: {
      user: token,
    }
  }
}
```

The `getServerSideProps` function in your page will **block the rendering of the page** until the function has been resolved. Further reading: [Routing in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).

Comment: "The getServerSideProps function in your page will block the rendering of the page until the function has been resolved. Further reading: Routing in Next.js." that sounds good

Comment: `redirect: { destination: '/', permanent: false, }` this looks wrong!

Comment: Sorry, it should be `return redirect`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Where should I place the `login` function??

Comment: In another page in `pages` folder. Place your function there, and place the `getServerSideProps` in the `/` page.

Comment: Where does the `redirect` comes from?

Comment: It comes built in from Next.js. It is used to redirect to another page server-side. Further reading [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).

Comment: I am so glad you could help me. Thank you so much!